# View not rendering. No data from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

This is my second day after starting to learn `AngularJS`. My views are not loading after I added some routes and I am not sure why. These are my codes.

### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

### app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'CustomersController',
            templateUrl: 'app/views/customers.html'
        })
        .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/' });
  });
```

### customers.html

```
<h3>Customers</h3>
Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name" />
<br/><br/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in filtered = (customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse)">
        <td>{{ cust.name | uppercase }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.orderTotal | currency:'PLN' }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.joined | date}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<span> Total customers: {{ filtered.length }} </span>
```

### customersController.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .controller('CustomersController', function ($scope) { 
    'use strict';

    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;

    $scope.customers = [
      {
        joined: '2005-09-07', 
        name: 'Mayweather', 
        city: 'Brooklyn', 
        orderTotal: '43.1299'

      }, 
      {
        joined: '2005-09-07', 
        name: 'Jason', 
        city: 'Cleveland', 
        orderTotal: '89.8933'

      }, 
      {
        joined: '1999-08-27', 
        name: 'Jade', 
        city: 'Wroclaw', 
        orderTotal: '77.0092'

      }, 
      {
        joined: '2015-09-01', 
        name: 'David', 
        city: 'Accra', 
        orderTotal: '13.8465'
      }, 
      {
        joined: '2001-01-18', 
        name: 'Doyet',
        city: 'Paris',
        orderTotal: '23.9930'
      }];

    $scope.doSort = function (propName) {
        $scope.sortBy = propName;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

This is my tree structure:

```
.
├── angular-route.js
├── angulars.js
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   └── customersController.js
│   └── views
│       └── customers.html
├── index.html
└── zextra
    ├── helloworld.html
    └── ngrepeat.html

4 directories, 8 files
```

(The `zextra` folder is irrelevant)
And this is the error I'm getting in the console:

```
empty. nothing!
```

Any ideas why I am not seeing anything in the browser and yet no errors?

EDIT:
Question edited after main error fixed with help from Pankaj Parker.

Comment: `<script> src="angular-route.js"</script>`should be `<script src="angular-route.js"></script>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`angular-route.js` should be loaded before `app.js` as you wanted to access `ngRoute` module from `angular-route.js`. Currently its not available that's why this the above code in throwing an `[$injector:modulerr]` error.

**Change**

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/customersController.js"></script>
```

> Ensure `angular.js` & `angular-route.js` should have same versions like both should be on version `1.4.5`.

**Update**

`customersController.js` shouldn't create a module again & you should use `myApp`

Change

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
```

to

```
angular.module('myApp')
```

[**strong text**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MrxTtN9O9iL1mqdU7bzF?p=preview)

Comment: That remove the errors Pankaj, but now I don't see the data from the controller in the browser. Any help?

Comment: @siaw23 take a look at plunkr if you want further look

Comment: @siaw23 Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: hello Pankaj, can you please help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362474/no-data-in-view-after-creating-a-factory :)

Answer (score 1):

Misspelling, maybe?

```
<script> src="angular-route.js"</script>
```

It should be:

```
<script src="angular-route.js"></script>
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

The error is indicating ngRoute is not available. ngRoute is provided by angular-route.js.

Your script statement:

`<script> src="angular-route.js"</script>`

Does not specify src as an attribute and is instead being executed as javascript.

Properly, it should be:

`<script src="angular-route.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

There's a new syntax in 1.4 for using the filtered collection elsewhere

```
item in items | filter : x | orderBy : order | limitTo : limit as results
```

Comment: what would be difference..what is the problem with current `ng-repeat`?