# No data in view after creating a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It's my 2nd day learning AngularJS. I have a problem I can't tackle. Everything was working fine until I created a factory. I understand that factories/services are used to refactor code. So I took some code from the controller and sent them to a factory so I can have some data loaded, but well, it's not. These are my codes:

### index.html

```
(function() {
    var customerFactory = function() {
        var customers = [
          { 
            id: 1,
            joined: '2005-09-07', 
            name: 'Mayweather', 
            city: 'Brooklyn', 
            orderTotal: '43.1299',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Pencils',
                total: 9.9956
              }
            ]

          }, 
          {
            id: 2,
            joined: '2005-09-07', 
            name: 'Jason', 
            city: 'Cleveland', 
            orderTotal: '89.8933',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'iPad',
                total: 20.9956
              }
            ]  
          }, 
          {
            id: 3,
            joined: '1999-08-27', 
            name: 'Jade', 
            city: 'Wroclaw', 
            orderTotal: '77.0092',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Pillows',
                total: 12.2311
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            id: 4,
            joined: '2015-09-01', 
            name: 'David', 
            city: 'Accra', 
            orderTotal: '13.8465',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Serek',
                total: 11.4782
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            id: 5,
            joined: '2001-01-18', 
            name: 'Doyet',
            city: 'Paris',
            orderTotal: '23.9930',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Serek',
                total: 11.4782
              }
            ]
          }];

            //Defind factory object
            var factory = {};

            factory.getCustomers = function() {
                return customers;
            };

            return factory;

    };

            angular.module('myApp').factory('customerFactory', customerFactory);
}());
```

### app.js

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
      .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        'use strict';
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'CustomersController',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/customers.html'
            })
            .when('/orders/:customerId', {
                controller: 'OrdersController',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/orders.html'
            })
            .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/' });
      });

##customers.html
<h3>Customers</h3>
Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter.name" />
<br/><br/>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="cust in filtered = (customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse)">
        <td>{{ cust.name | uppercase }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.city }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.orderTotal | currency:'PLN' }}</td>
        <td>{{ cust.joined | date}}</td>
        <td><a href="#/orders/{{ cust.id }}">View Orders</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<span> Total customers: {{ filtered.length }} </span>
```

### customersController.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('CustomersController', function ($scope, customersFactory) { 
    'use strict';

    $scope.sortBy = 'name';
    $scope.reverse = false;
    $scope.customers = [];

    function init (){
        $scope.customers = customersFactory.getCustomers();
    }

    init();

    $scope.doSort = function (propName) {
        $scope.sortBy = propName;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
});
```

### orders.html

```
<h3>Orders</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
        <td>{{ order.product }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.total | currency:'PLN' }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### customersFactory.js

```
(function() {
    var customerFactory = function() {
        var customers = [
          { 
            id: 1,
            joined: '2005-09-07', 
            name: 'Mayweather', 
            city: 'Brooklyn', 
            orderTotal: '43.1299',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Pencils',
                total: 9.9956
              }
            ]

          }, 
          {
            id: 2,
            joined: '2005-09-07', 
            name: 'Jason', 
            city: 'Cleveland', 
            orderTotal: '89.8933',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'iPad',
                total: 20.9956
              }
            ]  
          }, 
          {
            id: 3,
            joined: '1999-08-27', 
            name: 'Jade', 
            city: 'Wroclaw', 
            orderTotal: '77.0092',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Pillows',
                total: 12.2311
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            id: 4,
            joined: '2015-09-01', 
            name: 'David', 
            city: 'Accra', 
            orderTotal: '13.8465',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Serek',
                total: 11.4782
              }
            ]
          }, 
          {
            id: 5,
            joined: '2001-01-18', 
            name: 'Doyet',
            city: 'Paris',
            orderTotal: '23.9930',
            orders: [
              {
                id: 1,
                product: 'Serek',
                total: 11.4782
              }
            ]
          }];

            //Defind factory object
            var factory = {};

            factory.getCustomers = function() {
                return customers;
            };

            return factory;

    };

            angular.module('myApp').factory('customerFactory', customerFactory);
}());
```

In the console from Chrome, I understand the `customers.html` file is not loading. How do I fix this?

Console

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/siaw/Desktop/angularjshelloworld/app/views/customers.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10661
angular.js:12416 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///Users/siaw/Desktop/angularjshelloworld/app/views/customers.html'.
    at Error (native)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:10661:11
    at sendReq (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:10480:9)
    at serverRequest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:10187:16)
    at processQueue (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:14634:28)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:14650:27
    at Scope.$eval (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:15878:28)
    at Scope.$digest (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:15689:31)
    at Scope.$apply (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:15986:24)
    at bootstrapApply (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:1658:15)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12416
angular.js:12416 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: app/views/customers.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$compile/tpload?p0=app%2Fviews%2Fcustomers.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
    at angular.js:68
    at handleError (angular.js:17565)
    at processQueue (angular.js:14634)
    at angular.js:14650
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15878)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15689)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15986)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1658)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4473)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1656)
```

I will appreciate any help.

EDIT:

I installed 'http-server' and now get the following:

Console:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: customersFactoryProvider <- customersFactory <- CustomersController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$injector/unpr?p0=customersFactoryProvider%20%3C-ustomersFactory%20%3C-%20CustomersController
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:68:12)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4284:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4432:39)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4289:45
    at getService (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4432:39)
    at invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4464:13)
    at Object.instantiate (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:4481:27)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:9108:28
    at $route.link (http://localhost:8080/angular-route.js:977:26)
    at invokeLinkFn (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.5/angular.js:8746:9)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12416ident.$get @ angular.js:9203invokeLinkFn @ angular.js:8748nodeLinkFn @ angular.js:8246compositeLinkFn @ angular.js:7637publicLinkFn @ angular.js:7512name.$get.boundTranscludeFn @ angular.js:7656controllersBoundTransclude @ angular.js:8273update @ angular-route.js:935parent.$get.Scope.$broadcast @ angular.js:16200(anonymous function) @ angular-route.js:619processQueue @ angular.js:14634(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14650parent.$get.Scope.$eval @ angular.js:15878parent.$get.Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15689parent.$get.Scope.$apply @ angular.js:15986done @ angular.js:10511completeRequest @ angular.js:10683requestLoaded @ angular.js:10624
favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

Which means there's something wrong with my code. Can someone please point me in some direction? Why is my "provider" unknown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `http-server` as a quick and easy solution to run your application upon and to help resolve your file loading issues:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Answer (score 3):

As you are asking for a `templateUrl` from the `$routeProvider` definition on basis of `$route` definition. It asks for `template` from the folder which  will making ajax with `file://` protocol which does gets failed. And it is getting failed as protocol `file://` doesn't accessible via ajax `$http`.

For fixing this You need to host your code on some server like `Apache/LAMP/WAMP` server, so that your folder will hosted & it will have an `http://` protocol.

Comment: Or you could run a node web server like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve). Then you can easily start the server from your project folder with `serve .` in your terminal.

Comment: that got me closer. Pankaj i opted for 'http-server' cause it's easier. But now I get a new kind of error. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's just a typo between CustomersFactory and CustomerFactory now.

Comment: in 'customersController.js' i changed `customersFactory` to `customerFactory`and now i get `ReferenceError: customersFactory is not defined
    at init` but it is defined. :(

Comment: Did you update both customersFactory references in your controller?