# AngularJS directive not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get a simple directive with a templateUrl to work and have thus far been unsuccessful. Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

testing.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">
    <test-directive></test-directive>
</body>
```

app.js

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller('myCtrl', function() {
  });

  app.directive("testDirective", function(){
      return{
          restrict: 'E',
          templateUrl: "test-directive.html"
      };
  });

})();
```

test-directive.html

```
<p>this is a test directive</p>
```

Comment: code seems ok? is there any console errors?

Comment: Is the templateUrl path correct? I have a feeling it is throwing a GET error on it isn't it?

Comment: I get these three errors: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/nsuwyn2/Documents/angular/test-directive.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/nsuwyn2/Documents/angular/test-directive.html'.

Comment: Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$compile/tpload?p0=test-directive.html

Comment: here its working http://plnkr.co/edit/0U2Gjo6hwG95odEfJR9b?p=preview

Comment: Your path is wrong to the html file as I suspected.

Comment: @NickSuwyn look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32362518/2435473

Comment: the simplest solution would be to keep both `testing.html` and `test-directive.html` on same path.

Comment: @PankajParkar I will try that out. I have a feeling that's it because it needs to use http.

Comment: @Rohit416 they are in the same path. I think the problem is what Pankaj mentioned. Testing it now.

Comment: @NickSuwyn got working?

Comment: Just finished setting up the server and sure enough that was it. Thank you, @PankajParkar!